# I am trying to extract semantic information from text

Tags: java, nlp, semantics, jaws-wordnet

I am using java.

Till now, I have implemented sentence detector, tokenizer and I am using WORDNET LIBRARY (via JAWS api) to find various meaning of words.

Basically I want to extract the semantic/context of the sentence so that it can be used for better search engine results.

Please share any information you think will help me, any tools, apis, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Although I see that through your use of WORDNET you are taking an ontological approach to semantic analysis I would just like to say that good results have been had (not just by myself but by Google and Wikipedia) by simply looking at the relative co-occurrence of words i.e. how often they are used in proximity to each other and through that the implication that they are somewhat connected in meaning.

For example using [Latent Semantic Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_analysis)

I'm not trying to push you in any direction I just found myself in a similar position a few years ago and had success with the above approach.

Good luck

Comment: Hi Duncan, Thanks i will make a note of that.  For the moment lets assume I am sticking with WORDNET atleast for a while (since i have just started working on it). Now, I have implemented the tokenizer & am getting tokens from the sentence. I have 2 quesitons now: 1)how do i use the POS tagger to get better info about the query?. 2)now via JAWS i am retrieving various meanings of each token. how can i use it for my purpose?(because i think its purpose is while ranking to compute similarity, etc) (really confused!!)

Comment: Sadly once I'd switched approaches I had no need to look back. I guess it all depends on what you mean by "better" search results. Perhaps grouping potentially semantically similar results together? [link](http://cs.binghamton.edu/~meng/pub.d/Waim07final.pdf)

Comment: alright Duncan, could you provide me with some guidance to implement latent semantic analysis.. I want to study this as it is also more latest field. 
Links to few core papers and other material wud be very very helpful.